# How to get a hold of standard input while submitting a scala challenge on hackerrank.com

Tags: stdin

Solving HackerRank's challenges using Scala.

For challenges such as "Swap Nodes" I need to get a hold of the standard input. How?

Comment: This is not a question about Scala.  I'd guess, for instance, that you'd have the same problem in Java.  Retag.

Comment: True. I had no tags available to me though that made sense. And i cant create a new tag yet.

Comment: Retagged as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is essentially on how to read from stdin without much headache.

For Hackerrank I switched from scala.io.Source.stdin to use the functions such as readInt() and readLine(). I do not think that getLines returns you an empty iterator, did you try toList? The advantage of using an iterator is a low memory footprint as only the actualy line is kept in memory.

So the problem in Question requires you to read in an integer N then gives you N lines of integer pairs or -1. Then it follows an integer T and in T lines single numbers k.

```
val N = readInt()

// process these into a tree structure
val edges : Seq[Array[Int]] = 
    for (_ <- 1 to N) 
       yield readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)

val T = readInt()

for (_ <- 1 to T) {
   val k = readInt()
   // process k
}
```

Another trick is if you say read a line with two integers a, b you can read them as follows:

```
val Array(a,b) = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It was totally my own bug :(

Comment: and yes, your code for reading input is much clearer than mine. so thanks again

Comment: as soon as I get 15 reputation. I am new to this site.